# bijective continuous map and the preimage of a convergent sequence

Tags: metric-spaces

## At first my question

---

Let $X,Y$ are metric spaces with $X$ compact also let $T : X \to Y$ be a bijective continuous map and $(y_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ a sequence of $Y$. Is it true the following fact? $$(y_n) \text{ convergent } \implies (T^{-1} y_n) \text{ Cauchy }$$

Or the more general? $$(y_n) \text{ Cauchy } \implies (T^{-1} y_n) \text{ Cauchy }$$

Is the assumption that $X$ is a compact space necessary?

---

**And now the story behind**

I came across the following problem about compact metric spaces

> Let $X,Y$ are metric spaces and moreover $X$ is compact, also let $T : X \to Y$ be a bijective continuous map.
>
> Prove that $T^{-1}$ is continuous

I am aware of the proof by contradiction. However a tried to make a direct proof but I got stuck.

*my attempt*

---

*The map $T^{-1}$ is continuous if for every convergent sequence $(y_n) \subseteq Y$, with $\lim y_n=y$, it follows that $\lim T^{-1}y_n=T^{-1}y$*

*Let $(y_n)$ be a sequence of $Y$ such that $\lim y_n=y$*

*The fact that $X$ is compact and $T$ continuous implies that there is a subsequence, $(T^{-1} y_{k_n})$ , of $(T^{-1}y_n)$ such that* $$\lim T^{-1} y_{k_n}=T^{-1} y$$

---

This is where a got stuck.

If a prove that $(T^{-1}y_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence.Then the fact that it has a convergent subsequence implies that $(T^{-1}y_n)$ and moreover $\lim T^{-1} y_{k_n}=\lim T^{-1} y$

Thank you for your time

Comment: Do you know that if $f$ is uniformly continuous, $(x_n)$ Cauchy, then $f(x_n)$ is also cauchy?

Comment: no, but  i think that i can prove it. How is this related to my qeustion?

Comment: Oh there are several problems that you are asking. So the main problem is proving inverse is also continuous? Do you know continuous image of compact set is compact then?

Comment: Continuity on compact space means uniform continuity. So it follows that $T^{-1}$ of cauchy sequence is also cauchy

Comment: Well I am just keep throwing out propositions. So which you are going to prove first? Feel free to ask if you have doubts…

Comment: @LiChunMin my main quastion is if $T^{-1}$ of a Cauchy seqeunce is Cauchy, when T is continuous and $X$ compact. And moreover if compactness of $X$ is necessary. 

I tried to make clear how this question came up, but it seems that all the other stuff that I wrote are missleading.

Comment: Well I think you did a great job. I didn't go that far and just blindly follow the proofs when I studied analysis just last semester…I think compactness is nessesary to ensure that the inverse is uniformly continuous. If we take away compactness, what kind of domain do you want to have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to both questions is "yes", and the assumption that $X$ is compact is necessary for both. Foobaz John has already provided an elegant proof for the first question, but here is another: since $X$ is compact, it suffices to show that $T^{-1}y$ is the only limit point of $\{T^{-1}y_n\}$ where $y=\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n$. But if $T^{-1}y_{n_k}\to x_0$, by continuity of $T$ we have $y_{n_k}\to Tx_0$, so $y=Tx_0$, i.e. $x_0=T^{-1}y$. This completes the proof.

For the second question: since $X$ is compact and $Y=T(X)$, with $T$ continuous, we know $Y$ is also compact. In particular, $Y$ is complete, so $\{y_n\}$ Cauchy implies $\{y_n\}$ convergent. Now we can just defer to the first question.

To see compactness is necessary as an assumption, consider $X=[0,1)$, $Y=\{z\in\mathbb C:|z|=1\}$ and $T(x)=e^{2\pi i x}$. Then $T$ is continuous and bijective, but $T^{-1}$ is not continuous. Moreover, even if we knew $T^{-1}$ was continuous, this would not necessarily mean $\{y_n\}$ Cauchy implies $\{T^{-1}y_n\}$ Cauchy; for that we would need uniform continuity (which is automatic in compact spaces, providing another proof for the second question).

Answer (score 2):

It suffices to prove that the map $T$ is closed in order to show that $T$ is a homeomoprhism. To this end, let $E$ be a closed subset of $X$. Since $X$ is compact, it follows that $E$ is compact. Since $T$ is continuous, the continuous image of a compact set is compact and hence $T(E)$ is compact. But compact sets are closed (since $Y$ is a metric space); hence, $T(E)$ is closed as desired.

For your first question, since $T:X\to Y$ is a homeomorphism (as we have shown), it follows that $y_n\to y$ implies that $T^{-1}(y_n)\to T^{-1}(y)$ so that $T^{-1}(y_n)$ is Cauchy (as convergent sequences are clearly cauchy). The second question is similar since $T(X)$ is compact and hence complete. Thus if $\{y_n\}$ is Cauchy in $Y$, then it converges and we can use the answer of the previous question. The assumption that $X$ is compact is necessary as there exist continuous bijective maps which are not homeomorphisms (for example, the map $f:[0,1)\to S^1$ given by $f(x)=(\cos2\pi x,\sin 2\pi x)$.

Comment: what it means for a map to be closed?

Comment: @ karhas The map $T$ is closed means that if $E$ is closed in$ X$, then $T(E)$ is closed in Y. It is equivalent to showing that the preimage of closed sets under $T^{-1}$ is closed because $T$ is a bijection..